# Will PhoneGap or Android be better for this app idea?

Tags: java, android, html, cordova

I am planning on developing an app that uses the camera, uploads pictures to a website, displays all of the photos taken in the app and gives the user a little editing ability.  Would this be better developed using PhoneGap or the native Android development setup through Eclipse.  I know a good amount of Java and HTML so that isn't the big issue but I want to know which development kit I should use to get the app up more quickly while maintaining a decent interface.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end it all comes down to 2 things:

```
      1.- which language do you know better? consider that android IS NOT java, but knowing java will help a lot

      2.- Do you want this app to work only on the Android OS or you want it to work in every platform?
```

If your worries are interfaces, then don't worry. You can create very nice interfaces on both.